# cordova build fails after displaying environment variable

Tags: android, cordova, build

I searched in SO and others forums but couldn't find one thread related to my problem.

After I rm'd android platform and reinstalled it I have this error message displaying right after the normal display of the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables:

> The specified path was not found

Here's the full log:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Pierrick\AppData\Local\Android1
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
The specified path was not found.
(node:19256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
(node:19256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's the ouptut of cordova requirements:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

My environment variables are good and Java and Android is well installed at the location.

I tried to rm the platform one more time but the error is still there.

I never saw this error, I don't know what's causing it, nothing about it on google.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

After running command with -d option, I had the background operations log that allowed me to see that cordova was searching in "Android Studio" program directory but my installation was in "Android Studio 1" since I reinstalled it without cleaning all files from the previous installation.

Hope this will help some in the future.